# Transfer data in a ListBox to SQL database

Tags: sql, vb.net, listbox

I using Visual Studio 2010.My problem is; I can not transfer all data in a listbox to SQL Database. 
codes are as follows.

```
    Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New  SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(adaptor4)
    Dim insert_komut As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    datakayit4 = kayit4.Tables("aaaaa").NewRow

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ListBox5.Items.Count

        datakayit4("m_fabricno") = ListBox5.Items.Item(i)

    Next

    kayit4.Tables("bakimkaydi").Rows.Add(datakayit4)
    adaptor4.Update(kayit4, "aaaaa")
```

How can get rid of this problem ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Your code only adds one row to the table.

You need to add rows inside the loop.
This way, you can add multiple rows to the table.

Comment: Move the two lines that create and add the row inside your `For` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your code is replacing the same row over and over in the loop, you need to add the row for each item in the listbox

```
Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New  SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(adaptor4)
    Dim insert_komut As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ListBox5.Items.Count
        datakayit4 = kayit4.Tables("aaaaa").NewRow
        datakayit4("m_fabricno") = ListBox5.Items.Item(i)
        kayit4.Tables("bakimkaydi").Rows.Add(datakayit4)
        adaptor4.Update(kayit4, "aaaaa")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The problem solved.But , another the problem arised.For example ; I have my data etc 11,22,33 in order.it's good working transfer to SQL Database.But,the last row doing blank record.